# Read CSV file that contains data about pdf documents and store the information in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, repository, document

My CSV files have data like---

```
filename, title, docType
"abc.pdf","DesignDocument1", "design"
"125_df.pdf","testingDocument", "Test"
"abc4.pdf","","design"
```

I want in PHP to:---

1. read the CSV data row by row and store them in the database and
2. generate unique filename for each file and store them in specific folder

I am looking for table output like--

```
fileID          filename,       title,           doctype
00001           abc.pdf        DesignDocument1   design
00002           125_df.pdf     testingDecument   Test
00003           abc4.pdf       design
```

I will appreciate any suggestion/procedure to do them efficiently

I apology for my bad English

Comment: If you want to use PHP to do this, take a look at the [`fgetcsv()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use LOAD DATA INFILE:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourfilename.txt' INTO TABLE yourtablename (col1,col2,...);
```

In PHP, you'd run the query similar to this:

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourfilename.txt' INTO TABLE `yourtablename` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';",$con)
```